# как получить имя столбца в MYSQL

Tags: mysql, jdbc

Здравствуйте, подскажите как из таблицы с колонками id,name при использовании JDBC получить имя столбца(id,name).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как обычно все элементарно:

```
    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
    ResultSet set = statement.executeQuery("select * from a limit 0;");
    ResultSetMetaData data = set.getMetaData();

    int count = data.getColumnCount();

    for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
        System.out.print(data.getColumnName(i)+"\n");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
String sql = "SELECT id, name FROM Employees";
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
String id = rsmd.getColumnName(1);
String name = rsmd.getColumnName(2);
```

Comment: Это будет работать только если уже известны имена столбцов.
Нашел запрос, но он возвращает какой-то список названий в котором есть и мои названия (SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns)

Comment: Ваше решение не имеет никакого отношения к JDBC, а имеет к особенностям конкретной СУБД.

Comment: Хорошо я понял, буду копаться в запросах.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, IS_NULLABLE, COLUMN_DEFAULT
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'ИМЯ ТАБЛИЦЫ'
[AND table_schema = 'ИМЯ СХЕМЫ']
```